Passing FragmentActivity from React Native to Kotlin library
I have been trying to pass FragmentActivity from React Native to Kotlin Library.
This is the code from RN side.
public class RNSecureKeystoreModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements ActivityEventListener {
  private final KeyGeneratorImpl keyGenerator = new KeyGeneratorImpl();
  private final CipherBoxImpl cipherBox = new CipherBoxImpl();
  private final Biometrics biometrics;
  private final SecureKeystoreImpl keystore;
  private final DeviceCapability deviceCapability;
  private final String logTag;

  @ReactMethod
  public RNSecureKeystoreModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);

    FragmentActivity activity=(FragmentActivity)getCurrentActivity();
    this.biometrics = new Biometrics(activity);
    this.keystore = new SecureKeystoreImpl(keyGenerator, cipherBox, biometrics);
    this.deviceCapability = new DeviceCapability(keystore, keyGenerator, biometrics);
    this.logTag = Util.Companion.getLogTag(getClass().getSimpleName());
  }


My activity is null always, how can I solve this?
Here's how I receive my Fragment activity.
`class Biometrics(
private val context: Context,
) {
And here's why fragment activity is needed.
private suspend fun authenticate(
        createCryptoObject: () -> CryptoObject,
        action: (CryptoObject) -> Unit,
        createCryptoObjectSuccess: Boolean,
    ) {
        return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            val fragmentActivity = context as? FragmentActivity
                ?: throw NullPointerException("Context is not a FragmentActivity")
            fragmentActivity.runOnUiThread {
                try {
                    val onAuthSuccess: (CryptoObject?) -> Unit =
                        { cryptoObject -> action(cryptoObject ?: createCryptoObject()) }
                    val authCallback: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback =
                        BiometricPromptAuthCallback(continuation, onAuthSuccess)
                    val executor: Executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

                    val promptInfo = createPromptInfo()
                    val biometricPrompt =
                        **BiometricPrompt(context as FragmentActivity, executor, authCallback)**

                    if (createCryptoObjectSuccess) {
                        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo, createCryptoObject())
                    } else {
                        try {
                            biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            Log.e(logTag, e.toString())
                        }

                    }

                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e(logTag, "exception in creating auth prompt: ", e)
                    continuation.resumeWithException(RuntimeException("exception in creating auth prompt"))
                }
            }
        }
    }

`
Please help me bring this to a closure
